# Sorting a list based on number of vowels in the words in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7

How do I sort a list based on number of vowels in the words in python?

I have not found the answer on any website.
The word should be in descending order of number of vowels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) or `list.sort`.

Specify `key` with function that count the number of vowels. (The return value of the function is used as comparison key.)

Pass `reverse=True` argument to order descending.

```
>>> word_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'pineapple']
>>> sorted(word_list,
...        key=lambda word: sum(ch in 'aeiou' for ch in word),
...        reverse=True)
['pineapple', 'banana', 'apple']
```

Comment: minor detail; ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') could be written as 'aeiou'

Comment: Can you please explain "key=lambda word: sum(ch in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') for ch in word)"         what does 'word' mean here?

Comment: @user3194076, each item of the list is passed to the key function. `word` is the item. (a parameter of the lambda)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by creating two functions as follows

```
def vowel_count_test(string):
    count=0
    for z in string:
        if z in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            count=count+1
    return count
def sort_by_vowel_count(words):
    return words.sort(key=vowel_count_test,reverse=True)
```